# Data Explorer Cache

Tags: feature-request, support, data-explorer

In Stack Exchange Data Explorer, I noticed that after a query is executed, it is stored in the cache (I think). How do I disable this feature?

For example, when I run this query, it should generate a random decimal number every time it runs. However, after the first execution, it is returning the same output. How do I fix that?

Query:

```
SELECT RAND();
```

Output:

```
1st Output: 0.43478413831866264
2nd Output: 0.43478413831866264
3rd Output: 0.43478413831866264
```

Data Explorer Links:
Revision 01: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1017263/1256481
Revision 02: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1017263/1256480
Revision 03: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1017263/1256479

Same query on SQLFiddle.com: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/40059/0

```
1st Output: 0.7295917643723033
2nd Output: 0.42465768701227824
3rd Output: 0.8141123124641404
```

<sup>Update:
 
Please note that this SQL code is just an example.</sup>

Comment: Related: [SEDE query results are not refreshing. Can we have a “don't cache” option added?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190795/295232) I don't think you can fix it, except maybe with some clever userscript that adds a random guid as parameter each time you execute a query.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Laurel's idea and my own comment: suppose you have [a query with a parameter named `seed`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1017345/this-is-just-a-random-query). Then you can hook on running the query and give the seed a new value with this small JavaScript snippet:

```js
$("#runQueryForm").submit(function(event) {
    $("input[name='seed']").attr("value", Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 31))); 
});
```

You can run the code in your browser console, and I've made it part of my userscript that [restores the old functionality of automatically filling the user ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209605/295232), which has now been rebranded as [SEDE Parameter Autofiller](https://stackapps.com/q/8136/34061).

[image]

Comment: It's either executing that in the console, or installing a userscript. There's no way to do this in a more user-friendly way.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like SEDE cache maps the raw SQL to the results.

So to get a fresh result, just change the SQL. (Comments don't count, sadly)

Easiest way in this case is adding 0:

```sql
SELECT RAND() + 0
```

Then you can also:

```sql
SELECT RAND() + 0.0
```

And:

```sql
SELECT RAND() + 0.00
```

etc...

Comment: @DxTx " data explorer can be used as a demo website to show outputs" - no, please don't. It's not what it exists for, and if it will be abused too much SE will shut it down. So please, just don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

> Note that if the query requires you to fill in parameters before running, you'll only get the cached results if you enter the same values as were specified for the cached run...

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300199/323179

You get random results with `select rand(), ##seed##` then inputting a different seed each time.

Comment: @DxTx `select rand(); select ##seed##;`?